# Adding an instance of a class in to an array list in a different class, automatically upon creation of the instance

Tags: java, arrays, class, arraylist, dependencies

Fairly new to programming so not sure if what I'm asking is actually possible.

I have one class, `Man`, which just contains the parameters for the class, and also has some get methods to find the objects specific parameters.

I have another class, `Group`, in which I want to have an `ArrayList` of `Man`.

By the way I'm learning using the bluej environment, if that makes a difference.

Here is the relevant section from the `Man` class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
/**
*This class will store information about man, including the height, weight, age and year of birth
*of individual men.
*/
public class Man
{
// stats.
public int Height;
public int Weight;
public int Age;
public int Year;


/**
 * The user will input the stats about the man in input parameters.
 */
public Man(int Height, int Weight, int Age, int Year)
{
    this.Height = Height;
    this.Weight = Weight;
    this.Age = Age;
    this.Year = Year;
  }
```

There are then some get methods for the stats below these.

In my other class, `Group`, I want all instances of the class above to go in to an `ArrayList`.
So far I have:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
/**
*Record all men.
*/
public class Group
{

public ArrayList <Man> AllMen;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Group
 */
public Group()
{
    AllMen = new ArrayList <Man>();
}

public void AddMan(int Height, int Weight, int Age, int Year) {
    AllMen.add(new Man(Height, Weight, Age, Year,)); //trying to get it to list all men created.
}

}
```

The two of them don't seem to be connecting in the way I thought they would. What am I missing?

Comment: And the exact problem is? What did you expect and what did you get?

Comment: I was expecting (or hoping) that when I created a man object it would automatically move to the AllMen array list, but the it doesn't recognise Man in the Group class.

Comment: Well you seem to be doing fine in your `AddMan` method. I'm not a Java developer, but if `Group` doesn't see `Man`, that could be because both classes are not in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

if i'm not wrong then, you have to create object of your Man class in your Group class than you use it's all instance variables and method

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried that and the program doesn't seem to have a problem, but now the Man class is not appearing on my object bench, meaning I can't run the methods in it. Do you know how I access them? Thanks.